# Return by reference and operator chaining

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value, chaining

Why return by reference for operator chaining?

I've looked at so many answers on SO and the stock phrase is "return by reference to allow operator chaining", but without an explanation I don't see why I can't do it some other way.

For example, this seems to compile on my system and works fine, and the chaining works:

```
TestClass operator+=(TestClass tc){
    somePrivateValue += tc.somePrivateValue;
    return *this;
}
```

Where I can also do this:

```
TestClass& operator+=(TestClass& tc){
    somePrivateValue += tc.somePrivateValue;
    return *this;
}
```

Excluding the fact the second example doesn't require the copy constructor to be called for `TestClass` what are the other advantages?

Comment: The first one compiles, but does it really do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and the chaining works

No, it doesn't.

```
TestClass a = some_value;
TestClass b = some_other_value;
(a += b) += b;
```

Now check the value of `a`, however that's done. Does it reflect being incremented by `b` twice? Or only once?

Comment: Quite right. I was only looking at the case `a += b += c`, not the bracketed case like you have above which changes the order of evaluation. Cleared up now :) thanks.